# Efficiency of FGLS (Feasible GLS) estimator

Tags: self-study, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, generalized-least-squares

I hava the following model

$$y=X\beta+u$$

where y and u are $(n\times 1)$ a matrix  with full column rank and $\beta$ is an unknown $(k\times 1)$ vector of parameters.

$E(u)=0$ and $var(u)=\sigma^2 V$ where V is $(n\times n)$ symmetric and positive definite non diagonal matrix

And $u_t=\phi u_{t-1}+v_t$ and $u_t=v_t+\theta v_{t-1}$ where $\theta $ is an unknown parameter with $|\theta |<1$

I want to discuss the efficiency of the estimator obtained as follows

> For that, use Feasible GLS.
>
> (i) I run the regression $y=X\beta+u$ to obtain $\hat{u_t}$
>
> (ii)by using $\hat{u_t}$, I run the auxiliary regression $u_t=\phi u_{t-1}+v_t$ to obtain $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{v_t}$
>
> (iii) by using $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{v_t}$, find the variance covariance matrix $\omega = \sigma^2 \hat{V}$ and
>
> apply GLS to get $\hat{\beta_{FGLS}}=(X’\hat{V}^{-1}X)^{-1}X’\hat{V}^{-1}y$

Please share your ideas about the efficiency of this estimator. I think that we ignore $u_t=v_t+\theta v_{t-1}$. Thus, it is not efficient. But how can explain this in correct way?

Comment: Your question suggests that $u_t$ *simultaneously* is an AR(1) *and* an MA(1) process, which is impossible. Can you clarify? Do you mean to say that an AR(1) is fitted to the residuals while the true process is MA(1) (or vice versa)?